# A film about a boy and his big idea for society?

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is what I remember:

A boy, living on a farm or so, tells someone, could've been the postman, about his idea, his big idea for society and the world. It's about being good, sharing or something similar altruistic. And the postman answers what a great idea it is and silently takes it with him. In fact he starts, by accident to spread "the idea" and then the idea gains momentum, like a big wave washing around the globe.

Then, one day, the boy has already given up on it, has forgotten about the idea or so. But in the end of the film, the idea comes back to him, when someone presents exactly his idea to him, doing good, sharing or similar. The boy's idea has come full circle.

Can anyone identify this plot. Can anyone name this movie?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The plot sounds like [Pay It Forward](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0223897/) but I don't recall a farm scene.  Do you have any additional info?  Year?

Comment: Pay it forward also has a pretty tragic element. What with the important death near the end. That's an element I'd expect to stick in the mind.

Comment: Yes, Haley Joel "Sixth Sense" Osment seems familiar as the leading boy. Roughly 10 years old fits as well. House on a farm - or not. I think, you've found the one. Thumbs up!

Comment: Yes, confirmed. Pay It Forward was the movie I was looking for! Re-watched it yesterday :) Believe it or not - it took me another 6 years since the original post...